# How to map nested JSON object keys in React?

Tags: json, reactjs

I have Json like this. 
If the key is "alanlar" I need to get into the child object. 
"alanlar" nested objects have definite but I don't know how many nested "alanlar" are json. 
Json structure like as follows

Example: "kimlikKarti" object has "alanlar".
Path -> (kimlikKarti.musteriSoyadi , ***kimlikKarti.musteriAdi***).

Second step: **"musteriAdi"** has "alanlar". 
Path ->(***musteriAdi.alan1***).

Third step **"alan1"** has "alanlar".
Path ->(***alan1.alan2***)

Full path -> *kimlikKarti.musteriAdi.alan1.alan2*

i need loop how many nested "alanlar" object. And push a string list all full paths. Path and fullpath is only a string.

Actually What I really need is the concat names of nested objects base "alanlar".

```
{
                "alanlar": {
                    "kimlikKarti": {
                        "alanAdi": "kimlikKarti",
                        "alanEtiketi": "Kimlik Kartı",
                        "aciklama": "Ad, soyad gibi kimlik bilgilerini içeren bir form alan grubu",
                        "alanlar": {
                            "musteriSoyadi": {
                                "alanAdi": "musteriSoyadi",
                                "alanEtiketi": "Müşteri Soyadı",
                                "aciklama": "Başvuru sahibinin soyadı"
                            },
                            "musteriAdi": {
                                "alanAdi": "musteriAdi",
                                "alanEtiketi": "Müşteri Adı",
                                "aciklama": "Başvuru sahibinin adı",
                                "alanlar": {
                                 "alan1": {
                                   "alanAdi": "Alan Adı",
                                   "alanlar": {
                                     "alan2":{
                                       "alanSon": "Son Alan",
                                       "alanAdi": "Alan Adı"
                                      }
                                  }
                                }
                              }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "basvuruTarihi": {
                        "alanAdi": "basvuruTarihi",
                        "alanEtiketi": "Başvuru Tarihi",
                        "aciklama": "Formun doldurulduğu tarih",
                        "alanlar": {
                            "alan2": {
                                "alanAdi": "musteriSoyadi",
                                "alanEtiketi": "Müşteri Soyadı",
                                "aciklama": "Başvuru sahibinin soyadı",
                            },
                            "alan1": {
                                "alanAdi": "musteriAdi",
                                "alanEtiketi": "Müşteri Adı",
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

I need mapping structure like this.

> kimlikKarti.musteriSoyadi
>
> kimlikKarti.musteriAdi.alan1.alan2
>
> basvuruTarihi.alan2
>
> basvuruTarihi.alan1

Comment: can you share your attempt please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my solution.

```
const getPaths = (primeKey: string, obj: any, paths: any = []) => {
        for (var key in obj) {
            obj[key][primeKey] ?
                paths.push(key + "/" + getPaths(primeKey, obj[key][primeKey]))
                :
                paths.push(key)
        }
        return paths;
    }
    var pathList = getPaths('alanlar', obj['alanlar']);
    var pathArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < pathList.length; i++) {
        var paths = pathList[i].split(',');
        pathArray.push(paths);
    }

    let path: any, subPath: any;
    var parseObjectKeys = (obj: any, firstItem: any) => {
        for (var prop in obj) {
            if (firstItem in obj) {
                if (firstItem == prop) {
                    path = subPath;
                }
            }
            else {
                subPath = obj.alanAdi;
                var sub = obj[prop];
                if (typeof (sub) == "object") {
                    parseObjectKeys(sub, firstItem);
                }
            }
        }
        return path;
    }

    var parentObjKey, fullPath, pathItem;
    const getKey = (paths: any) => {
        var allPathList = [];
        for (var t = 0; t < paths.length; t++) {
            pathItem = paths[t];
            for (var a = 0; a < pathItem.length; a++) {
                var path = [];
                var firstItem = pathItem[a].split('/')[0];
                var fullItem = pathItem[a].replace(new RegExp("/", "g"), '.');
                parentObjKey = parseObjectKeys(obj, firstItem);
                if (typeof parentObjKey == 'undefined') {
                    allPathList.push(pathItem[a].replace(new RegExp("/", "g"), '.'));
                }
                else {
                    while (typeof parentObjKey != 'undefined') {
                        path.push(parentObjKey);
                        parentObjKey = parseObjectKeys(obj, parentObjKey);
                    }
                    var reversedPath = path.reverse();
                    fullPath = reversedPath.join('.') + '.' + fullItem;
                    allPathList.push(fullPath);
                }
            }
        }
        return allPathList;
    }
```

This list is what i need.

```
var keyList = getKey(pathArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const getPaths = (primeKey, obj, paths = []) => {
    for (key in obj) {
        obj[key][primeKey] ?
            paths.push(key + "/" + getPaths(primeKey, obj[key][primeKey]))
            :
            paths.push(key)
    }
    return paths;
}

console.log(getPaths('alanlar', data['alanlar']))
```

output :

```
[ 'kimlikKarti/musteriSoyadi,musteriAdi/alan1/alan2',
  'basvuruTarihi/alan2,alan1' ]
```

**which means :**

kimlikKarti / musteriSoyadi

kimlikKarti / musteriAdi / alan1 / alan2

basvuruTarihi / alan1

basvuruTarihi / alan2

Comment: This algorithm works well. By working on it, i got what i wanted.